# Uncaught TypeError: property "__reactFiber$wqjvbwadizh" is non-configurable and can't be deleted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, web-component

There are two web components which are being hosted in respective servers. I can view the web components individually.

**Server A:**

```
VIEW: abc.com/a/index.html

CONFIGURATION
abc.com/a/a.js
abc.com/a/main.css
<a-webcomponent>
```

**Server B:**

```
VIEW: abc.com/b/index.html

CONFIGURATION
abc.com/b/b.js
abc.com/b/main.css
<b-webcomponent>
```

Now I have a new React Project where I am trying to display both of these web components. So in my `index.html` I configured both `a-webcomponent` and `b-webcomponent` to view them in one project.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   
    <script src="abc.com/a/a.js"></script>
    <link href="abc.com/a/main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="abc.com/b/b.js"></script>
    <link href="abc.com/b/main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

ROUTES

```
<Route path="/a-webcomponent" Component={AWebComponent} />
<Route path="/b-webcomponent" Component={BWebComponent} />
```

AWebComponent

```
return <a-webcomponent />
```

BWebComponent

```
return <b-webcomponent />
```

PROBLEM

On Switching Routes, I get the following error.

> Uncaught TypeError: property "__reactFiber$wqjvbwadizh" is non-configurable and can't be deleted

Answer (score 2):

nonono,

A.html and B.html has hosted,you can not combine them together simplely just like you did,there are two ways:

1)reconstrutor your web,copy A.html and B.html into New.html,drop old A and B,and host New.then visit New.html.

2)use iframe,but this way just make people visit A & B,you will lose organic and overall in develop your work.

Comment: I really appreciate this logic of conditionally changing index.html while visiting a specific web component. . I will try this. . Using iframe is out of scope due to security issues.

Comment: I cannot combine A and B together. .They have to be separated. However I will try doing the conditionally update of index.html first.

Comment: yep, you can try consider Micro-Frontends, [micro-frontends.org](https://micro-frontends.org/),it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this was to downgrade the react-dom version.

Using react-dom@17.0.2 works.